# Do I really need to call actions by wrapping them into dispatch() call?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to Redux and I never was endeavoring to use it in my projects since there's so much boilerplate and it's hard for me to read and understand Redux code. In October 2019 they released Redux-Toolkit which aims to solve the problem of excessive boilerplate and to make Redux usage easier so currently I'm migrating my old application to React hooks and Redux-Toolkit and I'm doing so by examples (I like to learn things this way) and I don't quite understand where and why I need to use `useDispatch` hook. So I have this simple slice:

```js
const formSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'form',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setDefaultOrigin: (state, { payload }: { payload: UserGeo }) => {
            state.formsData.segments[0].origin = {
                code: payload.iata,
                text: payload.name,
                type: 'city'
            }
        },
        setWholePlace: (state, { payload }: { payload: { place: SearchHistorySegmentPlace, segment: number, type: 'origin' | 'destination' } }) => {
            state.formsData.segments[payload.segment][payload.type] = payload.place
        },
        setDate: (state, { payload }: { payload: { segment: number, type: 'there' | 'thence', date: string } }) => {
            state.formsData.segments[payload.segment].dates[payload.type] = payload.date
        },
        addForm: (state, { payload }: { payload: ReactMouseEvent }) => {
            if (!payload.currentTarget.classList.contains('disabled')) return

            const newSegment: SearchHistorySegment = {
                origin: state.formsData.segments[state.formsData.mode === 'simple' ? 0 : state.formsData.segments.length - 1].destination,
                destination: {
                    text: '',
                    code: '',
                    type: 'city'
                },
                dates: {
                    there: '',
                    thence: ''
                }
            }

            state.formsData.segments.push(newSegment)

            if (state.formsData.mode === 'simple') {
                state.formsData.mode = 'complex'
            }
        },
        removeForm: (state, { payload }: { payload: ReactMouseEvent }) => {
            if (!payload.currentTarget.classList.contains('disabled')) return

            state.formsData.segments.pop()

            if (state.formsData.segments.length === 1) {
                state.formsData.mode = 'simple'
            }
        },
        goToSimpleMode: state => {
            state.formsData.segments = [state.formsData.segments[0]]
            state.formsData.mode = 'simple'
        },
        handleAutocompleteChange: (state, { payload }: { payload: HandleAutocompleteParams }) => {
            state.formsData.segments[payload.formToChange][payload.type] = payload.segment
        },
        handleSwap: (state, { payload }: { payload: { segment: 0 } }) => {
            const origin = { ...state.formsData.segments[payload.segment].origin }
            const destination = { ...state.formsData.segments[payload.segment].destination }

            state.formsData.segments[payload.segment].origin = destination
            state.formsData.segments[payload.segment].destination = origin
        },
        setShowForms: (state, { payload }: { payload: boolean }) => {
            state.showForms = payload
        }
    },
})
```

And I export reducer and actions like so:

```js
export const stateSelector = (state: RootState): FormStackState => state.form

export const {
    setDefaultOrigin,
    setWholePlace,
    setDate,
    addForm,
    removeForm,
    goToSimpleMode,
    handleAutocompleteChange,
    handleSwap,
    setShowForms
} = formSlice.actions
```

Then I simply import those actions and call them directly, like

```
<button onClick={() => addForm()} />
```

But I see a lot of examples where people call actions by wrapping them in `dispatch`, which is returned by `useDispatch` hooks. What is the purpose of `useDispatch` and where I should or shouldn't use it when calling actions?

Comment: There is a difference between creating an action and dispatching it [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/react-redux-hooks/blob/master/src/components/Counter/CounterContainer.js#L22-L28) is some code of an example container that uses dispatch to dispatch an action created by action creator. It seems that using redux and createSlice is a bit redendant since you are now combining actions and reducers (event and reducer for the event) making the event store a bit useless. If one action always causes one reducer to handle it you may as well use context.

Comment: I am just going to make a guess here, but I think it would make the action be called separately and it won't be handled by redux batching process which queues these actions when you are calling them and batches them. That would be my guess for why you need to call them with dispatch function.